# How do I call my kernel module which writes to a proc file?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, proc

I copied and pasted the code from this url: http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html

I replaced the outdated &proc_root foolery and commented out the "Our_Proc_File->owner    = THIS_MODULE;" line on account that it gave me trouble while building.

I then made an appropriate makefile, compiled the .ko and did the deed with insmod.

Two questions:

1. How do I read from the procfile?
2. Also, I see an entry for the file is made at module load, but when is this file written?

*BONUS*
These questions may root from a misunderstanding of proc. It is my impression that proc "files" are written to upon file read to deliver up-to-date info.

1. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With `read(2)`. `cat` can do this for you from the shell.
2. Never. The contents are created dynamically when the file is read. This is why we specify a read callback for the file.

Comment: when I cat my profile from the command line, I noticed it seems like my procfile_read doesn't get called. It gives me ">" until I Ctrl+C and then I dmesg and don't see the text in my read method. Why is that, do you think?